# Flutter_Messaging Do Not Play Sound on a Real Android Phone

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-notification

Currently, I have implemented the Firebase Cloud Messaging on my application. The notification is function in foreground and background.

When I run the app on emulator, the sound is play with the default music. Once I run on a real Android device, there is the notification but without any notification sound. Can someone show me where is the problems?

Comment: same here, also no vibrate, need help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a higher priority in the JSON you send to the client, you have all the documentation here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

Comment: Do you have any sample format to put the priority when sending the notification? I have try a few way but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Solution is found and the format should be data:{notification:{sound: default, ...}}